# What will happen if we assign child handle to parent handle and the result in case of accessing parent handle?

Tags: system-verilog

Problem statement: there are 2 classes (parent and child class). Both have same `display` function in it. I have assigned child class handle to parent class handle by "`p=c;`" after that, I was trying to access `p.display()`, but in my understanding it should use function from child class. But, after run, I see it is printing from parent class. Any clue why?

```
class parent;
  function void display();
    $display("I am in parent");
  endfunction
endclass

class child extends parent;
  function void display();
    $display("I am in child");
  endfunction
endclass

module tb;
  parent p;
  child c;

  initial begin
    p = new();
    c = new();
    $display("1: %d    %d", p , c);
    p = c ;
    $display("%d    %d", p , c);
    p.display();

  end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is nearly identical to the example in IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 8.14 *Overridden members*.  The behavior of your simulation is thoroughly described there:

> To call the overridden method via a base class object (p in the
> example), the method needs to be declared virtual.

To get `p.display` to `I am in child`, you should declare your `display` functions as `virtual`:

```
class parent;
  virtual function void display();
    $display("I am in parent");
  endfunction
endclass

class child extends parent;
  virtual function void display();
    $display("I am in child");
  endfunction
endclass
```

Answer (score 0):

*Parent* and *child* are poor choices for describing class inheritance. When you construct an extended class, there is only one object which contains both the base and extended class properties.

When you use a base class variable to access properties in an extended class object, you can only access the properties known to the base class variable's type.

So when you use the `p` class variable, it will call parent::display() even though child::display exists, but it is hidden.

If you declare parent::display as a virtual method, only then will it look for the most extended override of that method.